# Rust: build for atmega16

Tags: rust, embedded, atmega16

I would like to write a simple program and compile it for atmega16. How do I add atmega16 as a compilation target? There are little to no docs about this...

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this document](https://book.avr-rust.com/)? It describes exporting the JSON spec for the built-in atmega328 target which you can then modify and use for other targets.

Comment: I've created an `atmega16.json` file but now I'm getting an error `'atmega16p' is not a recognized processor for this target ...`

Comment: Specifically section 3 of the of the document harmic linked.  Better to ask a question specifically about the issues arising from following those instructions rather than complain about little documentation, when this seems definitive.  Your inability to understand the available documentation seems to be the issue here, not lack of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The only built-in AVR target is avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328. If you are using a different AVR microcontroller, you need a custom target.

The [AVR-Rust Guidebook](https://book.avr-rust.com/) describes how to add custom targets for different AVR microcontrollers. The process boils down to:

1. Export the JSON specification for the built-in atmega328 target, to use as a template

   ```
   rustc --print target-spec-json -Z unstable-options --target avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328 > avr-unknown-gnu-atmega16.json
   ```
2. Edit this JSON file. I found that to get it to compile for atmega16, I had to change the following:

   ```
   "cpu": "atmega16",
   "is-builtin": false,
   "-mmcu=atmega16"
   ```

   Note:

   - The CPU is specified as "atmega16" not "atmega16p" as you had attempted to use
   - I don't have any atmega16 MCU to hand so I have not been able to test the resulting binary. You may need to tweak other elements of the file.
   - You will also need to install `avr-gcc`, as Rust uses it to link the resulting binary. You can get that [here](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/microchip-studio/gcc-compilers).
3. You should then be able to build your project like this:

   ```
   cargo build -Z build-std=core --target ./avr-unknown-gnu-atmega16.json --release
   ```

   Note that `--target` is specified as the path to the JSON file. If in the same directory, prefix with `./`.